# Is it possible to make a list of classes without instantiating them as actual objects?

Tags: java

I have a set of classes in my program which can be instantiated. Each class has a static method associated with it which updates a particular aspect of that class.

At run time the program chooses to use a number of the classes from the set.

Multiple versions of these classes are then instantiated as objects as the program runs.

Throughout the program there are key points where I need to call the static methods associated with the various classes but only the ones in use that the program picked at run time.

Is it possible for me to make a list/array containing the classes in use without instantiating them? So that I can then just go through that list and call the static method on each class?

The only other way I have found of doing it is instantiating one object for each class in use and storing them in an array and calling the methods from there. This seems a bit inefficient and not very elegant.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a class to call a static method on it...

Comment: Yes. I know that. But it seems to me you can't make a list of classes with out instantiating them as objects. Which defeats the point of what I am trying to do.

Comment: `List<Class<?>>` seems like what you want. To add a class to it: `myList.add(FooBar.class);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use reflection to do something like this:

```
List <Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

// alternatively, classes.add(com.foo.MyClass1.class);
classes.add(Class.forName("com.foo.MyClass1"));  
classes.add(Class.forName("com.foo.MyClass2"));
// ...etc

Method m = classes.get(0).getDeclaredMethod("staticFunction");
m.invoke(null); // pass in an instance of the class if this is an instance method
```

Check out the javadoc for [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html).

Comment: I can't seem to find a .getDeclaredMethod() which just takes characters. Should this contain the name of the method I want to call? Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)) is what you're looking for - `parameterTypes` are optional if there are no parameters

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you want to avoid instantiation, but if the only thing you are doing is calling static methods, there is not reason to create objects. As for your question, you can create an Array of Classes without any problem. Remember that MyClass.class is actually an object of class Class, so this would work :

```
Class[] classes = new Class[] {MyClass1.class, MyClass2.class};
```

You can then use your logic to select some of them. When done, you can instantiate them using reflection :

```
classes[0].newInstance();
```

Hope it helps, if not, please precise your question. Note that the class objects themselves will be created (not sure you can prevent the class loader to load them).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a list of Class objects such as

`List<Class> myClasses = new ArrayList<Class>();`

To add an item to the list you code something like `myClasses.add(Class1.class);`

That's one way to store a list of classes, without needing to create an instance of each one.